# React TypeError: items.map is not a function componentDidMount/< this.setState({

Tags: reactjs, rest

I have stupid mistake.

Than I try to use this url: https://api.unsplash.com/photos?client_id=...&page=1
It's OK

Than I try to use this url: https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=...&page=1&query=office
It's failed:

TypeError: items.map is not a function
render
src/App.js:51

```html
  48 |   </div>
  49 | </nav>
  50 | 
> 51 | <div className="row container text-center">
     | ^  52 | {items.map(item => (
```

componentDidMount/<
src/App.js:27

```html
  24 | fetch('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=ce566471febd4bbaa975c83517a1d9e74e9fd8f309a104de1f5881b07ee936cc&page=1&query=office')
  25 |     .then(res => res.json())
  26 |     .then(json => {
> 27 |         this.setState({
     | ^  28 |             isLoaded: true,
```

My App.js code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

// const Child = ({match}) => (
//     <div>
//       <h1>ID: {match.params.tag}</h1>
//     </div>
//   )

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            isLoaded: false
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=...&page=1&query=office')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    items: json
                });
            });
    }
  render() {
    var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;
        if (!isLoaded) {
            return "<div>Loading...</div>";
        }
    return (
      <Router>
      <div className="App">
       <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
        <div className="container">
          <a className="navbar-brand">MediaPark</a>
          <form className="form-inline">
            <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"></input>
            <button className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div className="row container text-center">
        {items.map(item => (
          <div className="card col-md-4" key="{item.id}">
              <img class="card-img-top" src={item.urls.thumb} alt="{item.id}"></img>
              <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">{item.id}</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">{item.description}</p>
                  <a href={item.urls.raw} class="btn btn-primary">Full image</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        
      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Why I get error TypeError: items.map is not a function, then I use prevouse URL it was OK. I want to create a search by new REST API url.

Comment: log the value of `json` here: `.then(json => {
 console.log('json', json);
    this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        items: json
    });
});` and check it should be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the API Documentation the data you get back from a search is an object looking like below. That means that you have to do the map on the results property. You get back an object and not an array.
So if you just want the results it would probably work doing something like this for you:

```
this.setState({
  isLoaded: true,
  items: json.results
});
```

https://unsplash.com/documentation

```
{
  "total": 133,
  "total_pages": 7,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "eOLpJytrbsQ",
      "created_at": "2014-11-18T14:35:36-05:00",
      "width": 4000,
      "height": 3000,
      "color": "#A7A2A1",
      "likes": 286,
      "liked_by_user": false,
      "description": "A man drinking a coffee.",
      "user": {
        "id": "Ul0QVz12Goo",
        "username": "ugmonk",
        "name": "Jeff Sheldon",
        "first_name": "Jeff",
        "last_name": "Sheldon",
        "instagram_username": "instantgrammer",
        "twitter_username": "ugmonk",
        "portfolio_url": "http://ugmonk.com/",
        "profile_image": {
          "small": "https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1441298803695-accd94000cac?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=32&w=32&s=7cfe3b93750cb0c93e2f7caec08b5a41",
          "medium": "https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1441298803695-accd94000cac?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=64&w=64&s=5a9dc749c43ce5bd60870b129a40902f",
          "large": "https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1441298803695-accd94000cac?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=128&w=128&s=32085a077889586df88bfbe406692202"
        },
        "links": {
          "self": "https://api.unsplash.com/users/ugmonk",
          "html": "http://unsplash.com/@ugmonk",
          "photos": "https://api.unsplash.com/users/ugmonk/photos",
          "likes": "https://api.unsplash.com/users/ugmonk/likes"
        }
      },
      "current_user_collections": [],
      "urls": {
        "raw": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1416339306562-f3d12fefd36f",
        "full": "https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1416339306562-f3d12fefd36f",
        "regular": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1416339306562-f3d12fefd36f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&s=92f3e02f63678acc8416d044e189f515",
        "small": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1416339306562-f3d12fefd36f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=263af33585f9d32af39d165b000845eb",
        "thumb": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1416339306562-f3d12fefd36f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&fit=max&s=8aae34cf35df31a592f0bef16e6342ef"
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/eOLpJytrbsQ",
        "html": "http://unsplash.com/photos/eOLpJytrbsQ",
        "download": "http://unsplash.com/photos/eOLpJytrbsQ/download"
      }
    },
    // more photos ...
  ]
}
```